# Invalid enum value in a list doesn't get caught in .NET configuration but get its object removed from the list?

Tags: asp.net, .net

I have a configuration section in appsettings.json that encapsulates a list:

```
"MiscSettings": [
    {
      "Name": "Invalid",
      "TheEnum": "OneX"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Valid",
      "TheEnum": "Two"
    }
  ]
```

Model:

```
 public class MiscSettings
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public TheEnum TheEnum { get; set; }
    }
    public enum TheEnum
    {
        One, Two, Three
    }
```

And in Program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddOptions<List<MiscSettings>>().BindConfiguration("MiscSettings");
```

now, when injecting an IOptions<List>:

```
public ValuesController(IOptions<List<MiscSettings>> options)
{
    var val = options.Value.First().Name; // Name: Valid
    var count = options.Value.Count; // 1
}
```

It doesn't yield any exception, it just ignores the whole object, unlike the case with single object binding:

```
"MiscSettingsSingle":
    {
      "Name": "Invalid",
      "TheEnum": "OneX"
    }
```

In Program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddOptions<MiscSettings>().BindConfiguration("MiscSettingsSingle");
```

Then it will throw an exception:

```
public ValuesController(IOptions<List<MiscSettings>> options)
{
    var val = options.Value.Name; // Failed to convert configuration value at 'MiscSettingsSingle:TheEnum' to type 'WebApplication1.TheEnum'.'
}
```

So my question is: how to catch invalid conversions in a list of items bound from appsettings.json, and also apply Data annotation, for example, if I used `RangeAttribute` on integer value in a list, it won't be applied

Comment: What do you want this to do if the item does not match the enum? You need to do something custom then

Comment: At least I know there is a problem in the configurations, suppose this was shipped and the array contains 50 items, and only 49 are processed, due to a problem in the data of one item